# Why ExecutorCompletionService doesn't have the option to block when adding results to the completionQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a producer consumer example. The producer is submitting tasks to an [ExecutorCompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) that does some fast processing and add the result to its internal `completionQueue`, an unbounded [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). From here a consumer takes the results.

The interesting fact is that `ExecutorCompletionService` is using `add` method to output results in the queue and `add` doesn't block. What if I have a slow consumer and I want the `ExecutorCompletionService` to block to avoid memory overflow?

Here is the relevant code in the `ExecutorCompletionService` class, with javadoc stating that the `completionQueue` should be treated as unbounded. Why?

```
public class ExecutorCompletionService<V> implements CompletionService<V> {
private final Executor executor;
private final AbstractExecutorService aes;
private final BlockingQueue<Future<V>> completionQueue;

/**
 * FutureTask extension to enqueue upon completion
 */
private class QueueingFuture extends FutureTask<Void> {
    QueueingFuture(RunnableFuture<V> task) {
        super(task, null);
        this.task = task;
    }
    protected void done() { completionQueue.add(task); }
    private final Future<V> task;

 }

...

 /**
     * Creates an ExecutorCompletionService using the supplied
     * executor for base task execution and a
     * {@link LinkedBlockingQueue} as a completion queue.
     *
     * @param executor the executor to use
     * @throws NullPointerException if executor is {@code null}
     */
    public ExecutorCompletionService(Executor executor) {
        if (executor == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.executor = executor;
        this.aes = (executor instanceof AbstractExecutorService) ?
            (AbstractExecutorService) executor : null;
        this.completionQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Future<V>>();
    }

    /**
     * Creates an ExecutorCompletionService using the supplied
     * executor for base task execution and the supplied queue as its
     * completion queue.
     *
     * @param executor the executor to use
     * @param completionQueue the queue to use as the completion queue
     *        normally one dedicated for use by this service. This
     *        queue is treated as unbounded -- failed attempted
     *        {@code Queue.add} operations for completed tasks cause
     *        them not to be retrievable.
     * @throws NullPointerException if executor or completionQueue are {@code null}
     */
    public ExecutorCompletionService(Executor executor,
                                     BlockingQueue<Future<V>> completionQueue) {
        if (executor == null || completionQueue == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.executor = executor;
        this.aes = (executor instanceof AbstractExecutorService) ?
            (AbstractExecutorService) executor : null;
        this.completionQueue = completionQueue;
    }

...

public Future<V> take() throws InterruptedException {
    return completionQueue.take();
}

}
```

As a side note, there is a way to throttle the input into the `ExecutorCompletionService` if the task processing is slow.

Comment: As the documentation says, "_... failed attempted `Queue.add` operations for completed tasks cause them not to be retrievable_". In other words, the completion service has no way to gracefully handle a full queue. In this case the task is simply lost to oblivion. But what if it was designed for a bounded queue? What should be the strategy? Retry to add the completed task? How many attempts? What's the backoff strategy? Should it use `put` instead? What about the potential `InterruptedException`? How about a callback? And what about an API to configure all this?

Comment: Note you should be able to implement your own throttling code via a `Semaphore` or some equivalent.

Comment: @Slaw As I noted in the question, there is a solution to throttle the producer if the processing in the CompletionService is slow and it has many pending  tasks in the input queue. But this is not the case in question. The question is what can you do if the consumer that consumes from the output queue is slow? The results will fill up the unbounded output queue.

Comment: Your question is "_Why ExecutorCompletionService doesn't have the option to block when adding results to the completionQueue?_" and that's what my first comment attempted to address (via speculation)—regardless of fast producer, slow consumer or vice versa.

Comment: My second comment mentions `Semaphore` which you can use to throttle how fast producer tasks can be scheduled based on how fast the consumer is, well, consuming.